# Visual Studio Code with different settings

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible to pass settings.json file to Visual Studio Code? I need to use different settings depending on the project I am working on. I do for example need to use nodejs from the Ubuntu subsystem sometimes and nodejs from Windows sometimes.

It would even be better if I could run two completely different instances so that I also could have different plugins installed. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override or amend settings on a per-project basis. Just add the desired settings to `.vscode/settings.json` at the root of the project folder. You can not run different instances with different plugins short of installing the Insiders build aside the Stable one.